# С++. Как проверить входит ли число в диапазон

Tags: c++, float

Как узнать, будет ли число входить в допустимый диапазон для типа float после умножения в строке

> Result[i][j] += FirstValues[i][k] * SecondValues[k][j];

```
float **Matrix::Multiple(float **FirstValues, float **SecondValues, int FirstCol, int FirstRow, int SecondCol, int SecondRow)
{
    float **Result;

    Result = new float *[FirstCol];

    for (int i = 0; i < SecondRow; ++i)
    {
        Result[i] = new float[SecondRow];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < FirstRow; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < SecondCol; ++j)
        {
            Result[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < FirstCol; ++k)
            {
                Result[i][j] += FirstValues[i][k] * SecondValues[k][j];
            }
        }

    return Result;
}
```

Comment: при достижении переполнения результат будет неопределён. Так-что может быть поможет установка лимитов на числа : `1.8e-19 .. 1.8e+19` чтобы результат попал в возможность типа `float` `3.4e-38 .. 3.4e+38`

Comment: .. точнее так : `1e-19 .. 1.8e+19` из-за float : `1.1e-38 .. 3.4e+38`

Comment: Если вы не используете специальных опций компилятора для небезопасных оптимизаций арифметики с плавающей точкой (например, `-ffast-math` или `/fp:fast`), то скорее всего компилятор соблюдает требования Annex F IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic стандарта языка C. А значит при переполнении произведения в результате получится бесконечность. Это можно использовать. `#include <cmath> ... float val = FirstValues[i][k] * SecondValues[k][j]; if (std::isfinite(val)) Result[i][j] += val; else /* overflow */`.

Comment: попробую, спасибо